# Regex to find word starting and ending with ##

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, qregexp

I am using `##\b\S+?\b##` regex to find word starting and ending with ## which finds the below,

```
##YourFriend##
```

This does not work when there is a space in between words like

```
##Your Friend##
```

I need a regex which works for both the cases, that could find both,

```
 ##YourFriend##
 ##Your Friend##
```

I tried using `\s` which is used to find the white spaces, but it does not work.

Comment: I can't see why a non-greedy "match anything" `##.*?##` wouldn't be perfect for the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this: `##.*?##`.

Which will match the two ##s in a non greedy way.

Answer (score 3):

Use this: `##(.*?)##`.**'()'** is for grouping the matched value.

[image]